# MongoDB fields limitation in array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am looking for a way - and dont even now if this is possible - just to return a part of a list saved in mongodb.

Lets have a look in my currently document:

```
{
    _id : 'MyId',
    name : 'a string',
    conversations : [
        {
            user : 'Mike',
            input : 'Some input'
        },
        {
            user : 'Stephano',
            input : 'some other input'
        }
    ]

}
```

What I now want to do is smth like this:

```
var myOutput;
myOutput = db.my_collection.find(
{
    _id : 'MyId',
    'conversations.user' : 'Mike'
}, {
    _id : 1,
    name : 1,
    conversations : {
        $where : {
            user : 'Mike'
        }
    }
});
```

Goal is it just to get back the conversation array item where `user` has the value `Mike`.

Is this still possible in MongoDB ? didn't found any reference in the documentation for the field limitations in mongoDB.

Comment: the Mongodb documentation has multiple examples on how to use find.  Some are similar to what you need, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: I dont need a find example - how to find a document where this user is set is in my example - I need a way to limitate the returned value (just return a part of the array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [$ positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) in a projection:

```
> db.my_collection.find({ "_id" : "MyId", "conversations.user" : "Mike" },
                      { "_id" : 1, "name" : 1, "conversations.$" : 1 })
{
    "_id" : 'MyId',
    "name" : 'a string',
    "conversations" : [
        { "user" : 'Mike', "input" : 'Some input' }
    ]
}
```

This projects only first matching array element.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of the [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)?

```js
db.my_collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": "MyId"}}, { "$unwind": "$conversations"}, 
    { "$match": {"conversations.user": "Mike"}}
])
```

**Output**

```js
{ 
    "_id" : "MyId", 
    "name" : "a string", 
    "conversations" : 
    { 
        "user" : "Mike", 
        "input" : "Some input" 
    } 
}
```